# How to set a name for (not rename) a network interface in Windows from the command line?

Tags: windows, networking, cmd.exe

I found how to rename:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Old Name" newname="New Name"
```

or, with PowerShell:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Old Name" | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "New Name"
```

What I need is to set a name for an Ethernet card I do not know the name of. The reason I need this is that some computers I'm servicing remotely simply reset their IP configuration by themselves from time to time (this is what the clients claim) and I need to be able to set them back to a working configuration automatically. Upon fixing this issue, the script seems easy to build:

```
netsh interface ip set address "connection name"^
 static 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
netsh interface ip add dns "connection name" 8.8.8.8
netsh interface ip add dns "connection name" 208.67.220.220 index=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't name an interface, you can only rename it.

To get the current names of the interfaces on the computer you can use `netsh interface show interface` and then use some scripting fu to extract the name of the interface that you need.